# How to toString() a List like this one : List<Option>?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, tostring

Suppose I have a `list` of an object called `Option` :

```
List<Option> opts = ArrayList<Option>();
```

I have override `toString()` for the object `Option`.

when I do `opts.toString()` that means I do toString for a List , I get some unnecessary commas **,,,,,**.

I would like to change that. Please, is there a way better then for-looping inside the List to toString each element ? Hope I am clear.

Comment: You could remove the extra commas afterwards with a regex perhaps.

Comment: right, that's one way to do it.

Comment: Is that like Google Guava's Optional (or Java 8's Optional)? If yes, Guava has a method just for this: [`Optional.presentInstances(optionals)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#presentInstances(java.lang.Iterable))

Comment: Or if I misunderstood the question and the `Option` class is not meant to be a value meaning present/absent and you simply want to create a custom `toString()` representation of the `List`, you might use Guava's [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html), or Java 8's [`String.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

Comment: ArrayList's toString() only inserts commas between each element. So those "unnecessary commas" mean that some of you Option classes return empty string from their toString() instead of a meaningful text, which is probably wrong.

Comment: @Natix I would like to make more elaborate formatting. So, the commas are just an example. I may replace them by `\n` or `).\n`.

Comment: @OSryx So, the question is simply about joining a list of something? Then Guava's `Joiner`, Apache Commons `StringUtils` or Java 8's `String.join()` or `StringJoiner` are the answers (and I'm sure Spring also has a utility like this). If you can't go for either of these, you need to write a custom utility method / class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not a good idea to override `toString` of `ArrayList`, but you can create your own print function in some Utility class of your application:

```
public static String myToString(List<?> list) {
    StringBuilder stringList = new StringBuilder();
    String delimiter = " ";
    for (int c = 0; c < list.size(); c++) {
        stringList.append(delimiter);
        stringList.append(list.get(c));
    }
    return stringList.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what  I did,  and it worked. I thought maybe there other alternatives , that's why I asked the question

Comment: The best place for this method would probably the the `Option` class itself.

Comment: @Slanec if he only uses this for `Option` yes.. but in an util class will mantain code clearer if used for more `List`s than `List<Option>`

Comment: @JordiCastilla Ah. I probably misread the question, you're right.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer OP's question, which regards the output of toString() when called on the list.

Comment: I answered in first line about overriding `toString` of `ArrayList`: **is not a good idea**, if I tell OP don't do this... I should actually give him some option...

Comment: `stringList += " " + list.get(c);` nooooo, don't concatenate new elements to result strings (each time it has to create new string which will be copy of previous result plus new element you want to add). Use `StringBuilder`, or maybe even better `StringJoiner` since you want to have delimiter.

Comment: @user1675642 because there are plenty of external elements that can use `List.toString()` in the background, you never know....

Comment: @JordiCastilla you presented first another solution using only String`, why did you change it ? please can you explain why in your answer ? thank u in advance.

Comment: Both sollutions do the same, but as pshemo pointed, `Strings` in Java are inmutable, that means each time you concatenate one `String` the JVM creates a new object, `StringBuilder` is more optimal in this case

Comment: `for(Option o: opts) stringList.append(delimiter).append(o);` will do the same as the loop above in a more compact fashion.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the string representations to be glued together you may use

```
opts.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

but if you just want get rid of the comma, i.e. keep a space as separator, you can customize it as

```
opts.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

or, if *obsolete* separators are you concern, i.e. you don’t want separators between empty strings, use

```
opts.stream().map(Object::toString)
    .filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

If you miss the brackets, use either

```
opts.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "[", "]"))
```

or

```
opts.stream().map(Object::toString)
    .filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "[", "]"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), it would look like this:

```
List<Optional<String>> opts = Arrays.asList(
   Optional.of("bli"),
   Optional.<String>empty(),
   Optional.of("bla"));

String result = opts.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

resulting in "bli, bla" without any extra commas.

If you can't use the official `Optional` class, you could maybe change your `Option` to behave similarly?

BTW: With Java 9 you could even replace the awkward `filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` with `flatMap(Optional::stream)`.

Comment: Option is a user made class. *class Option{}*

Comment: I am aware of that. My suggestion is to use `Optional` instead. If not possible, add an `isPresent` method to your class so it has similar semantics. Unless you also add a `get`, adjust the example to call your overridden `toString` inside `map`.